# Passing post request formData to Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, parameters, controller

I have been trying to have my front end send a JSON object with a set of data to my database. Using Postgres, there is a special migration that handles JSON as 'payload':

```
class CreateTournois < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :tournois do |t|
      t.json 'payload'
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Using `xmlhttp`, I submit my JSON to the model:

```
function save() {
  var tojs = myDiagram.model.toJSON();
  var json = JSON.stringify(tojs);

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('payload', json);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("post", "http://localhost:3000/malesingle", "application/json", true);
  request.send(formData);
}
```

And I use a basic form tag:

```
<%= form_for Tournoi.new do |f| %>
  <button id="SaveButton" onclick="save()">Save</button>
<% end %>
```

My controller is where I seem to have some issues:

```
 def create
   if @tournoi.nil?
     @tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params['payload']))
     @tournoi.save
     redirect_to  malesingle_url
   else
     redirect_to root_url
   end
 end
```

The content of my JSON object is inserted into the model and the change is saved into the data, but I get redirected to an error page even with the change being made.

I get this error on line 8 `@tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params['payload']))`.:

> TypeError no implicit conversion of nil into String

How can I get the params accepted by my controller?
I don't know if its relevant but i'm using GoJs Library for this here are the line where myDiagram is initialized :

```
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;  
  myDiagram =
    $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",        {
        initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,  // center the content
        "textEditingTool.starting": go.TextEditingTool.SingleClick,
        "textEditingTool.textValidation": isValidScore,
        layout: $(go.TreeLayout, { angle: 180 }),
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true
      });

  // validation function for editing text
  function isValidScore(textblock, oldstr, newstr) {
    if (newstr === "") return true;
    var num = parseInt(newstr, 10);
    return !isNaN(num) && num >= 0 && num <= 1;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking that up a bit?
```
payload = JSON.parse(params['payload'])
@tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: payload)
```
Or inspected `params['payload']` to ensure it's getting the right data? My guess is parsing the JSON is what is causing issues and there's some `nil` value somewhere it doesn't like. Possibly even `params['payload']`. Maybe similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038922/typeerror-no-implicit-conversion-of-nil-into-string-sinatra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error is always raised when using `@tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))`, The TypeError is raised specifically on **JSON.parse(params[:payload])**, by just modifying the **method create** :

```
def create
      if @tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: params['payload'])
          @tournoi.save
.......
```

Not parsing the params will save the payload but it will save another tournoi that has a payload nil, all i need to do is add a validation in my model to avoid a tournoi that has a nil payload to be saved :

```
class Tournoi < ApplicationRecord
  validates :payload, presence: true, allow_nil: false
```

When submitting into tournoi model the payload is inserted and commit, the db rollback on the second tournoi since the **payload** is nill

Answer (score 3):

If that can be of any help, I solved a similar issue by using `.to_json` like this

`JSON.parse(params.to_json)`

Comment: issue has been fixed a long time ago, thank you for the answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

`params['payload']` is `nil`. `JSON.parse(...)` throws this error if it's passed a `nil` value.

You could use the following to ensure the payload exists (if it's acceptable for there not to be a payload):

```
if @tournoi.nil? && params['payload']
  @tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params['payload']))
  ...
```

Otherwise, it will be a case of fixing the Javascript as that's not currently passing the payload as it should be. Perhaps add where `myDiagram` is defined and you'll be able to get a little more help on this as needed :)

Let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: Using `@tournoi.nil? && params['payload']` gets me a **noMethodError** on 'payload', yea i will add where my diagram is defined